# How to import lots of video files into React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**I just want to load videos upon request from within a React Component.** The user is currently shown a large list of .mp4 videos. When one is selected, the location of that video is passed to a video player modal via props. But when the play button is pressed, I get a 404 error saying the video couldn't be found.

At first, I tried putting all of the video files right inside the React src folder. Then, I tried moving them to the React public folder next to index.html. I also looked into import() to load one video at a time but got really confused and flat out stuck. So *there are currently no import or require statements for any of the videos.*

**Here is the relevant part of the MediaModal component code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";
import "../../node_modules/video-react/dist/video-react.css"; // import css
import { Player } from "video-react";

class MediaModal extends Component {
  render() {
    const { isShowing, selectedMedia } = this.props.itemStateObject;
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={isShowing} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            {isShowing && (
              <Player
                playsInline
                src={selectedMedia.location}
              />
            )}
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { closeModal }
)(MediaModal);
```

**The video source used by the video player above is generated by the server and has the form "media/series-title/season-number/video.mp4" The 404 error I receive is:
GET http://localhost:3000/media/series-title/season-number/video.mp4 404 (Not Found)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your files placed in a "public" folder where the webserver can pick them? Did you verified the permission for that folder? (If you are using Linux you need to see this) I had a similar problem for image files and solved this way. Take a look at the hyperlink for correctness.

Comment: Jose, yes I placed the files in a public folder. The directory permissions are rwxr-xr-x and the file permissions are r--r--r--. Does that look right to you? I was using Linux but I've been using Git Bash on Windows the last few days and the problem is the same.

Comment: There is a folder where all your React code is compiled into JavaScript. Try there!

Comment: I think that's what I've done. I put my media folder inside the client's "public" folder. I thought I could then refer to it using ./media... but no luck. Also, the hyperlink looks correct to me, assuming localhost:3000/media is the right way to access the media folder.

Comment: do not use localhost. Use the link the user will be visiting:
window.location.protocol + '//'+ window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port + "details for your file"

Comment: I tested that code directly in the modal component code like this: <Player src={window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + "/" + selectedMedia.location}/> but those variables don't return anything. The 404 error says ":/media/series-title/season-number/video.mp4" can't be found. Sorry, I keep trying to "@" you but having no luck.

Comment: which framework are you using? Sometimes, to retrieve files you need to arrange a routes (or similar) file which will allow users to access those mp4 files?

Comment: That part of the project just uses React, Redux, and Video-React (for the video player). For now the files are stored inside the client folder, so I thought they would be easy to access without complex routing. So frustrating... :/

Comment: you mean your app and the video files are in separated servers? If this is the case, you might need a dedicated webserver for the files or use a controller function -running on your server- that can be invocated from the web app and make it to show that video file. Java script runs on the user web page on a computer that can might not see the server with the video files.

Comment: My entire app is basically running on my computer for testing purposes. And the video files are on the client side. They are located in the public folder where the web server should see them: But, I don't know how to dynamically import one of them at runtime so I feel like that could be the problem.

Comment: I believe you need a webserver on the client's one. Imagine that your client is "youtube". YouTube has a webserver to offer the video files.

Comment: Jose, I think you're right. I've done a lot of research since I asked this question and this is probably the best and most practical solution. After all, it's not like all of those video files were going to stay where they are upon deployment.